# How to get element value and then use it in :contains jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to get the value of the h1 PHP echoed Page Title element then use that to find any match in the li PHP echoed category name and then if it matches add a class to the span. Is this possible in jquery?

```
<h1>PHP echoed Page Title</h1>
<ul>
<li><a href="">PHP echoed category name</a>
<span class="open">X</span>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">PHP echoed category name</a></li>
    <li><a href="">PHP echoed category name</a></li>
    <li><a href="">PHP echoed category name</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few assumptions baked into this solution.

Assumption 1:  The h1 is the only h1 on the page.

Assumption 2: The class you want to append is 'fooClass'

Assumption 3: You do not want to remove any other classes.

Assumption 4: You do not want to test for strict string equality in the li, you want to see if the text is present, you care about case, and generally don't want to do any regular expression / string massaging magic.

```
    header_text = $('h1').text();
    $('.open ul li').each(function(){
        if($(this).text().indexOf(header_text) != -1){
             $(this).parent().parent().addClass('fooClass');
             return(true); //this will terminate execution to avoid adding fooClass more then once.
        }           
    });
```